# Android HorizontalScrollView with weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create my custom switch, I used HorizontalScrollView , I have two LinearLayout and child linear is longer then parent, but scroll not working, my code is here, are there any suggestion why not working HorizontalScrollView?

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/c_horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1.0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/u_custom_switch_slide_efect"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33">
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:background="@drawable/view_corner_green"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/c_selected_hint"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Left"
                        android:textColor="@color/u_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_font_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:background="@color/u_black"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `android:weightSum` option is there to declare the maximum weight sum for a View's child Views, if not specified. Hence, you can't declare `android:weightSum="1.0"` in a LinearLayout and then `android:layout_weight="1.5"` to its child View as 1.5 is more than the total weight sum this view can allow. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) for more details.